# Not getting all cookies from Javascript site (python)

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I am trying to make a program that checks for ski lift reservation openings. So far I am able to get the correct response from the API but it only works for about 15 min before some cookie expires. Here is my current process.

Go to site: https://www.keystoneresort.com/plan-your-trip/lift-access/tickets.aspx and look at the network response, then I copy the highlighted xhr script as a curl(bash).
[website/api in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUYun.jpg)
I then take that curl(bash) and import it into postman and get the response:

[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyRJp.png)

Then I take the code from postman so I can run it in python
[Code used by postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9rAN.png)

```
import requests, json
url = "https://www.keystoneresort.com/api/LiftAccessApi/GetLiftTicketControlReservationInventory? 
startDate=01%2F21%2F2021&endDate=03%2F06%2F2021&_=1611254694375"
payload={}
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.keystoneresort.com',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
  'x-queueit-ajaxpageurl': 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.keystoneresort.com%2Fplan-your-trip%2Flift-        
access%2Ftickets.aspx%3FstartDate%3D01%252F23%252F2021%26numberOfDays%3D1%26ageGroup%3DAdult',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  '__requestverificationtoken': 'mbVIzNL1qZUKDT3Re8H9kXVNoYLmQPC-tgLCSbM_inVSN1v_2Pei-A-    GWDaKL7i6NRIVTr0lnlmiYACNvfmd6Zzsikk1:HI8y8wZJXMuP7nsTJwS-adYZu7FoHVPVHWY5naHRiB71dg2PzehuQa8WJy418eIrVqwmvhw-a1F34sJ425mXzWpEANE1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Mobile Safari/537.36',
  'save-data': 'off',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'referer': 'https://www.keystoneresort.com/plan-your-trip/lift-access/tickets.aspx?    startDate=01%2F23%2F2021&numberOfDays=1&ageGroup=Adult',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'cookie': 'QueueITAccepted-SDFrts345E-V3_vailresortsecomm1=EventId%3Dvailresortsecomm1%26QueueId%3D96d15411-09e1-4443-89a3-f0d6e4cef5d5%26RedirectType%3Dsafetynet%26IssueTime%3D1611254692%26Hash%3D06e1aecd2d5cdf64363d53f4fc63f1c22316f604895cd3ecfd1d8b03f86ba36a; TS019b45a2=01d73c084b0f6abf04d77ffeb9e37953f3d047ebae13a4f5ffa8e69045bf156b4959e093cf10f08359c6f45a491fdc474e068898a9; TS01f060ff=01d73c084b0f6abf04d77ffeb9e37953f3d047ebae13a4f5ffa8e69045bf156b4959e093cf10f08359c6f45a491fdc474e068898a9; AMCV_974C370453295F9A0A490D44%40AdobeOrg=1406116232%7CMCIDTS%7C18649%7CMCMID%7C30886069937558409272202898840476568322%7CMCAAMLH-1611859494%7C9%7CMCAAMB-1611859494%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1611261894s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C2.5.0;'
}
s = requests.Session()
y = s.get(url)
print(y)
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
todos = json.loads(response.text)
x = json.dumps(todos, indent = 2)
print(x)
```

Now if you run this in python, it will not work because the cookies will have expired for this session by the time someone tries it. So you would have to follow the process I listed above if you want to see what I am doing. The response I get looks like this, which is what I want but only for it not to expire.
[Python response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j01PR.png)

I have looked extensively at different ways I can get the cookies using requests and selneium. All solutions I have tried only get some of the cookies and not all of them. I need the ones that are in the "cookie" header listed in my code, but I have not found a way to do that without refreshing the page and posting the curl in postman and copying the response. I am still fairly new to python and coding in general so don't go to hard on me if the answer is super simple.

I think some of these cookies are rendered by java script, which may be part of the problem. I can also delete some of the cookies in my code and have it still work(until it expires). If there is an easier way to do what I am doing please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: chances are these are session cookies, so the server-side session variable will also expire.  There's nothing you can do about a server-side session var, so this is all may be pointless.  Having said that, I think the cookies you are wanting are set as "HTTP Only".  Selenium can't access those since they cannot be read via javascript.